# I have problem on incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

So, I'm trying to make a dashboard but couldn't fix this error when running it.[this is the error I got when running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGNtA.png)

This is my main.dart

```
import 'package:dashboard_invoice/constant.dart';
import 'package:dashboard_invoice/screens/invoice.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dashboard',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.ubuntuTextTheme()
              .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white, displayColor: iPrimaryColor)),
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Invoice(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So my main.dart connect to 2 file which is Invoice and Invoice Body

- invoice.dart

  ```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        invoiceHeader(context),
        const InvoiceBody()
      ],
    );
  }
  }

  Container invoiceHeader(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenConfig.init(context);
    return Container(
      width:ScreenConfig.devicewidth,
      height: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(374),
      color: const Color(0xFF33cdbb),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(50),
          left: ScreenConfig.getProportionalWidth(40),
          right: ScreenConfig.getProportionalWidth(40)),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text("Pembayaran",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(50)),
            ),
          ),
            SizedBox(
              height: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(10),
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text("Berhasil!",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(25)),
                )),
            SizedBox(
              height: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(15),),
            Positioned(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,//TRY TO CHANGE THIS **0.30** value to achieve your goal
                child: Container(
                  child:Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset('assets/icons/success.gif',height: 87)]),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,)
            )
          ],
        )],
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

-invoice_body.dart

```
import 'package:dashboard_invoice/constant.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class InvoiceBody extends StatelessWidget{
  const InvoiceBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16,top: 16,left: 16),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,right: 20,top: 12,bottom: 12),
                height: 200,
                width: ScreenConfig.getProportionalWidth(561),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87,width: 2,),
                  color: Colors.white,),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text("Nama",style:
                      GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black87,),),
                      Text("Tanggal",style:
                      GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black87,),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                      Text("Jam Masuk",style:
                      GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black87,),),
                      Text("Jam Keluar",style:
                      GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black87,),),
                      Text("Durasi Parkir",style:
                      GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black87,),),
                      Text("Biaya Parkir",style:
                      GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black87,),),
                    ],
                  ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text("Djoko Wirawan",style:
                    GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      color: Colors.black87,),),
                    Text("10 Januari 2022",style:
                    GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      color: Colors.black87,),),
                    Text("18:32",style:
                    GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      color: Colors.black87,),),
                    Text("19:32",style:
                    GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      color: Colors.black87,),),
                    Text("1 Jam",style:
                    GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      color: Colors.black87,),),
                    Text("Rp5.000",style:
                    GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      color: Colors.black87,),),
                  ],
                )],
              ),
                Row(
                children:[Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Text("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------",style:
                GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                  color: Colors.black87,),),
                  ],
                ),]),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(children: [
                    Text("Total Biaya",style:
                    GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      color: Colors.black87,),)],),
                  Column(children: [
                    Text("Rp5.000",style:
                    GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    color: Colors.black87,),)])
                ],)],)),]),
            Row(
              children: [
              Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16,left: 16),
            height: 150,
            width: ScreenConfig.getProportionalWidth(561),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8)),
                color: Color(0xFF98e6dd),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Color(0x10000000),
                      blurRadius: 10,
                      spreadRadius: 4,
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 8.0))]),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                    left:16,
                    top: 12,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/wallet.png',
                        height: 35,
                        width: 35)),
                Positioned(
                    top: 18,
                    left: 62,
                    child: Text('Sisa Saldo',
                      style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,),)),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Rp1.000.000",
                    style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                      fontSize: 35,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      color: Colors.grey,)
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

and this is a constant file but I don't think it affect the error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenConfig{
  static double devicewidth='' as double;
  static double deviceheight='' as double;
  static double designHeight = 1300;
  static double designWidth = 600;
  static init(BuildContext context) {
    devicewidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    deviceheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  }
  // Designer user 1300device height
  static double getProportionalHeight(height){
    return deviceheight * height / designHeight;
  }
  static double getProportionalWidth(width){
    return devicewidth * width / designWidth;
  }
}

// Colors
const iPrimaryColor = Color(0xFFDBDBDB);
const iAcccentColor = Color(0xFFFFB44B);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `Positioned` in a `Column` in invoice.dart. `Positioned` should be used in `Stack`

Try this:

```
Container invoiceHeader(BuildContext context) {
  ScreenConfig.init(context);
  return Container(
    width:ScreenConfig.devicewidth,
    height: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(374),
    color: const Color(0xFF33cdbb),
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(50),
        left: ScreenConfig.getProportionalWidth(40),
        right: ScreenConfig.getProportionalWidth(40)),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Pembayaran",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(50)),
          ),
        ),
          SizedBox(
            height: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(10),
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Berhasil!",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(25)),
              )),
          SizedBox(
            height: ScreenConfig.getProportionalHeight(15),),
          Container(
                child:Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset('assets/icons/success.gif',height: 87)]),
                alignment: Alignment.center,)
          )
        ],
      )],
    ),
  );
```